# Access children controls of a form control?

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamics-crm-online

I have moved from an older version of CRM to CRM online and I need to convert my javascript functions to be compatible with CRM online. I'm having a problem converting this script below to its equivalent for CRM Online:

```
var obj = document.getElementById(fieldName + '_c').children[0]; 

var childNodeArray =obj.childNodes;
obj.removeChild(childNodeArray[3]);
var parentElement=obj.parentElement;
childNodeArray =parentElement.childNodes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are now use CRM 2015/2016. And that means that your script is not valid anymore. It would be really hard or even impossible to convert your script to do the same action in CRM. I believe it is more appropriate to convert your code to supported (remove DOM manipulations from code) so can you please tell what your code should do?

Comment: Well, my ultimate goal is to set the tooltip of an option set label to concatenate the selected item label to that tooltip

Comment: You don't need anymore to do it starting from CRM 2013. Just populate description field of field and this message will be shown. Recheck this article - http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2013/09/06/dynamics-crm-2013-field-description-displayed-in-tooltip

Comment: Yes, but this would change the tooltip for all the records. I need to let the tooltip different from one record to another.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no supported way of doing it. To find working way to implement your requirement in unsupported way you will have to dig a lot...